# Verificar se variável contém um endereço de email bem formatado em PHP

Tags: php, email, variáveis, validação, formatação

A variável recebe um valor que supostamente será um endereço de email, mas surgem as dúvidas:

- Será um endereço de email, um texto aleatório, ou outra coisa qualquer?
- Sendo um endereço de email, está bem formatado?

Assumindo uma função `valida_email()` que iria devolver booleano:

```
echo valida_email("teste");                     // devolve FALSE
echo valida_email("teste@teste@teste.com");     // devolve FALSE
echo valida_email("testar.com");                // devolve FALSE
echo valida_email("teste mais@gmail.com");      // devolve FALSE
echo valida_email("téste@gmail.com");           // devolve FALSE
echo valida_email("teste@teste");               // devolve FALSE
echo valida_email(array("bubu@bubu.com"));      // devolve FALSE
echo valida_email("stackoverflow@bananas.com"); // devolve TRUE
```

#Pergunta

Em PHP, de que forma podemos validar se o conteúdo de uma variável é um endereço de email bem formatado?

---

<sup>**Nota:** Não interessa se existe ou não existe, interessa que seja um endereço de email válido mediantes as regras existentes que definem a formatação do mesmo, ver [RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-6.1) e [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) ambas em Inglês.</sup>

<sup>**Desambiguação:** Para validação com base no [RFC6530](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6530), por favor consultar as resposta [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39753/223).</sup>

Comment: Só não entendi o porque de echo valida_email(array("bubu@bubu.com")); devolver false sendo que nesse caso, passando um array poderia validar vários endereços de e-mail em uma única chamada.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz Apenas para ilustrar que a função neste exemplo espera uma `string` e não uma matriz ou um objecto, no sentido de manter as coisas simples, concentrado as resposta na validação da formatação em si, segui esse caminho. Mas a tua ideia é boa de qualquer forma.

Comment: @Zuul, cheguei aqui pelo termo IPV6... mas para dar um up na questão, **téste@gmail.com** passa ser válido. [**Gmail passa a reconhecer acentos**](http://tecnologia.terra.com.br/internet/gmail-passa-a-reconhecer-enderecos-de-e-mail-com-acento,8a72187ec28a7410VgnVCM3000009af154d0RCRD.html)

Comment: @PapaCharlie Abri uma [nova pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39753/223) para o RFC6530 de forma a não anular as respostas já presentes nesta. Obrigado pela informação cuja mesma me era alheia!

Answer (score 13):

Uma opção também é utilizando [filter_var()](http://www.php.net/filter_var):

```
function valida_email($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

Comment: Segundo os comentários no manual, isso falha com alguns emails, portanto não segue à risca as RFCs. Mesmo assim, acho uma boa ideia delegar o problema para o próprio PHP.

Comment: Sem dúvidas! Além de mais rápido do que validar coma ER não te deixa acordado de noite revisando tamanha complexidade na cabeça.

Comment: É 2015 e queria que mais pessoas usassem isso, ou melhor, solução compatível com e-mails internacionalizados, embora suponho que isso será suportado pelo PHP em um futuro (distante). Ao contrário, usam implementações próprias que permitem e-mails inválidos como "esse..exemplo@domin.io" ou que não permitem "esse-comum+exemplo@9mail.kon".

Answer (score 5):

Use essa biblioteca: http://code.google.com/p/isemail/downloads

Lembrando que dependendo da biblioteca seus resultados podem variar, por isso **é importante usar uma biblioteca**. Se você for usar um regex você vai acabar com algo tipo isso ([fonte 1](http://fightingforalostcause.net/content/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php), [fonte 2](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)):

```
/^(?!(?:(?:\x2`2?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\x22?
\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D
\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|
(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22))(?:\.(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-
\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*
\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,126}){1,}(?:
(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]
... é muito maior do que você imagina ...
```

Logo nunca use regex para validar e-mails!<sup>[1](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1zf7pi/learn_regex_interactively/cft7ll9)</sup>

Ainda mais porque com o surgimento de [TLDs internacionalizadas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Internationalized_country_code_top-level_domains) você poderá encontrar emails tipo `"esse e-mail é válido"@cachaça.com`,  `e-também-esse@blio.tk`. Esse último existe e é meu, ainda que pela especificação atual ele não seja válido já existem validadores que já estão considerando ele válido, [como esse](http://sphinx.mythic-beasts.com/~pdw/cgi-bin/emailvalidate).

Comment: Notem que o Gmail já está considerando e-mails internacionalizados como válidos, inclusive esses dois exemplificados. Se quiserem testar vão em Configurações → Contas e importação → Adicionar outro endereço → Use "seu-e-mail+âlgö-cóm-acêntós@gmail.com" e envie um e-mail com ele.

Answer (score 4):

A melhor maneira de verificar se um texto está dentro de um padrão pré-definido é usando expressões regulares. Certa ocasião um script em perl foi desenvolvido para gerar uma expressão que validasse um e-mail conforme o RFC822 e o resultado foi a seguinte expressão:

```
(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ 
\t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\0
31]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\
](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+
(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:
(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z
|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*)*\&lt;(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\
r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*
)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)
*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+
|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r
\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031
]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](
?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?
:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?
:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\&gt;(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)|(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?
:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?
[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] 
\000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|
\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;
@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"
(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?
:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[
\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-
\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(
?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*\&lt;(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;
:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([
^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\"
.\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\
]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\
[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\
r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] 
\000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]
|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \0
00-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\
.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,
;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?
:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*
(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".
\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[
^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]
]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\&gt;(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:,\s*(
?:(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[
\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?
:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|
\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:
[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\
]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*\&lt;(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["
()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;
@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,
;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?
(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".
\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[
"()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])
*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])
+|\Z|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\
.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z
|(?=[\["()&lt;&gt;@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\&gt;(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)?;\s*)
```

Infelizmente esse tipo de expressão acaba sendo muito custosa para a aplicação e, fora isso, você não quer que as pessoas acham que sua expressão é algum tipo de virus. Existem outras expressões mais simples para valizar emails – talvez não com o rigor do RFC822, mas bastante próximas disso:

```
/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i
```

[Nesse link](http://fightingforalostcause.net/content/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php), existem divcersos exemplos de expressões regulares e seus respectivos testes com vários tipos de e-mail. Escolha um e veja qual serve melhro aos seus propósitos. :)

Answer (score 2):

Baixe e utilize a função do link: https://github.com/PrimosTI/kit/blob/master/php/lib/mailparse.php

```
<?php
require_once 'mailparse.php';

$mail = 'mail@domain.com';
$analise = mail_parse_address($mail);

if($analise) {
    // E-mail bem-formatado
    switch($analise['type']) {
    case MAIL_ADDR_TYPE_HOSTNAME:
        // Você também pode verificar o tipo do endereço
        echo 'E-mail válido.\r\n';
        echo 'Usuário:' . $analise['local'] . '\r\n';
        echo 'Domínio:' . $analise['tag'] . '\r\n';
        break;
    case MAIL_ADDR_TYPE_IPV4:
    case MAIL_ADDR_TYPE_IPV6:
        // Aceita endereços do tipo IP.
        echo 'E-mail válido.\r\n';
        echo 'Usuário:' . $analise['local'] . '\r\n';
        echo 'IPv' . ($analise['type'] == MAIL_ADDR_TYPE_IPV4 ? '4' : '6' ) . ':' . $analise['tag'] . '\r\n';
        break;
    case MAIL_ADDR_TYPE_GENERIC:
        // Aceita endereços de tags
        echo 'E-mail válido.\r\n';
        echo 'Usuário:' . $analise['local'] . '\r\n';
        echo 'Tag:' . $analise['tag'] . '\r\n';
        break;
    case MAIL_ADDR_TYPE_IDN:
        // Estamos desenvolvendo o suporte aos endereços IDN,
        // contemplando os novos tipos de e-mail conforme os
        // novos padrões da internet.
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo usar a seguinte [função que implementa a RFC 822](https://raw.github.com/iamcal/rfc822/master/rfc822.php). Muito boa e fácil de usar:

```
<?php

#
# RFC 822/2822/5322 Email Parser
#
# By Cal Henderson <cal@iamcal.com>
#
# This code is dual licensed:
# CC Attribution-ShareAlike 2.5 - http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/
# GPLv3 - http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
#
# $Revision$
#

##################################################################################

function is_valid_email_address($email, $options=array()){

    #
    # you can pass a few different named options as a second argument,
    # but the defaults are usually a good choice.
    #

    $defaults = array(
        'allow_comments'    => true,
        'public_internet'   => true, # turn this off for 'strict' mode
    );

    $opts = array();
    foreach ($defaults as $k => $v) $opts[$k] = isset($options[$k]) ? $options[$k] : $v;
    $options = $opts;



    ####################################################################################
    #
    # NO-WS-CTL       =       %d1-8 /         ; US-ASCII control characters
    #                         %d11 /          ;  that do not include the
    #                         %d12 /          ;  carriage return, line feed,
    #                         %d14-31 /       ;  and white space characters
    #                         %d127
    # ALPHA          =  %x41-5A / %x61-7A   ; A-Z / a-z
    # DIGIT          =  %x30-39

    $no_ws_ctl  = "[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x7f]";
    $alpha      = "[\\x41-\\x5a\\x61-\\x7a]";
    $digit      = "[\\x30-\\x39]";
    $cr     = "\\x0d";
    $lf     = "\\x0a";
    $crlf       = "(?:$cr$lf)";


    ####################################################################################
    #
    # obs-char        =       %d0-9 / %d11 /          ; %d0-127 except CR and
    #                         %d12 / %d14-127         ;  LF
    # obs-text        =       *LF *CR *(obs-char *LF *CR)
    # text            =       %d1-9 /         ; Characters excluding CR and LF
    #                         %d11 /
    #                         %d12 /
    #                         %d14-127 /
    #                         obs-text
    # obs-qp          =       "\" (%d0-127)
    # quoted-pair     =       ("\" text) / obs-qp

    $obs_char   = "[\\x00-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f]";
    $obs_text   = "(?:$lf*$cr*(?:$obs_char$lf*$cr*)*)";
    $text       = "(?:[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f]|$obs_text)";

    #
    # there's an issue with the definition of 'text', since 'obs_text' can
    # be blank and that allows qp's with no character after the slash. we're
    # treating that as bad, so this just checks we have at least one
    # (non-CRLF) character
    #

    $text       = "(?:$lf*$cr*$obs_char$lf*$cr*)";
    $obs_qp     = "(?:\\x5c[\\x00-\\x7f])";
    $quoted_pair    = "(?:\\x5c$text|$obs_qp)";


    ####################################################################################
    #
    # obs-FWS         =       1*WSP *(CRLF 1*WSP)
    # FWS             =       ([*WSP CRLF] 1*WSP) /   ; Folding white space
    #                         obs-FWS
    # ctext           =       NO-WS-CTL /     ; Non white space controls
    #                         %d33-39 /       ; The rest of the US-ASCII
    #                         %d42-91 /       ;  characters not including "(",
    #                         %d93-126        ;  ")", or "\"
    # ccontent        =       ctext / quoted-pair / comment
    # comment         =       "(" *([FWS] ccontent) [FWS] ")"
    # CFWS            =       *([FWS] comment) (([FWS] comment) / FWS)

    #
    # note: we translate ccontent only partially to avoid an infinite loop
    # instead, we'll recursively strip *nested* comments before processing
    # the input. that will leave 'plain old comments' to be matched during
    # the main parse.
    #

    $wsp        = "[\\x20\\x09]";
    $obs_fws    = "(?:$wsp+(?:$crlf$wsp+)*)";
    $fws        = "(?:(?:(?:$wsp*$crlf)?$wsp+)|$obs_fws)";
    $ctext      = "(?:$no_ws_ctl|[\\x21-\\x27\\x2A-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7e])";
    $ccontent   = "(?:$ctext|$quoted_pair)";
    $comment    = "(?:\\x28(?:$fws?$ccontent)*$fws?\\x29)";
    $cfws       = "(?:(?:$fws?$comment)*(?:$fws?$comment|$fws))";


    #
    # these are the rules for removing *nested* comments. we'll just detect
    # outer comment and replace it with an empty comment, and recurse until
    # we stop.
    #

    $outer_ccontent_dull    = "(?:$fws?$ctext|$quoted_pair)";
    $outer_ccontent_nest    = "(?:$fws?$comment)";
    $outer_comment      = "(?:\\x28$outer_ccontent_dull*(?:$outer_ccontent_nest$outer_ccontent_dull*)+$fws?\\x29)";


    ####################################################################################
    #
    # atext           =       ALPHA / DIGIT / ; Any character except controls,
    #                         "!" / "#" /     ;  SP, and specials.
    #                         "$" / "%" /     ;  Used for atoms
    #                         "&" / "'" /
    #                         "*" / "+" /
    #                         "-" / "/" /
    #                         "=" / "?" /
    #                         "^" / "_" /
    #                         "`" / "{" /
    #                         "|" / "}" /
    #                         "~"
    # atom            =       [CFWS] 1*atext [CFWS]

    $atext      = "(?:$alpha|$digit|[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2a\\x2b\\x2d\\x2f\\x3d\\x3f\\x5e\\x5f\\x60\\x7b-\\x7e])";
    $atom       = "(?:$cfws?(?:$atext)+$cfws?)";


    ####################################################################################
    #
    # qtext           =       NO-WS-CTL /     ; Non white space controls
    #                         %d33 /          ; The rest of the US-ASCII
    #                         %d35-91 /       ;  characters not including "\"
    #                         %d93-126        ;  or the quote character
    # qcontent        =       qtext / quoted-pair
    # quoted-string   =       [CFWS]
    #                         DQUOTE *([FWS] qcontent) [FWS] DQUOTE
    #                         [CFWS]
    # word            =       atom / quoted-string

    $qtext      = "(?:$no_ws_ctl|[\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7e])";
    $qcontent   = "(?:$qtext|$quoted_pair)";
    $quoted_string  = "(?:$cfws?\\x22(?:$fws?$qcontent)*$fws?\\x22$cfws?)";

    #
    # changed the '*' to a '+' to require that quoted strings are not empty
    #

    $quoted_string  = "(?:$cfws?\\x22(?:$fws?$qcontent)+$fws?\\x22$cfws?)";
    $word       = "(?:$atom|$quoted_string)";


    ####################################################################################
    #
    # obs-local-part  =       word *("." word)
    # obs-domain      =       atom *("." atom)

    $obs_local_part = "(?:$word(?:\\x2e$word)*)";
    $obs_domain = "(?:$atom(?:\\x2e$atom)*)";


    ####################################################################################
    #
    # dot-atom-text   =       1*atext *("." 1*atext)
    # dot-atom        =       [CFWS] dot-atom-text [CFWS]

    $dot_atom_text  = "(?:$atext+(?:\\x2e$atext+)*)";
    $dot_atom   = "(?:$cfws?$dot_atom_text$cfws?)";


    ####################################################################################
    #
    # domain-literal  =       [CFWS] "[" *([FWS] dcontent) [FWS] "]" [CFWS]
    # dcontent        =       dtext / quoted-pair
    # dtext           =       NO-WS-CTL /     ; Non white space controls
    # 
    #                         %d33-90 /       ; The rest of the US-ASCII
    #                         %d94-126        ;  characters not including "[",
    #                                         ;  "]", or "\"

    $dtext      = "(?:$no_ws_ctl|[\\x21-\\x5a\\x5e-\\x7e])";
    $dcontent   = "(?:$dtext|$quoted_pair)";
    $domain_literal = "(?:$cfws?\\x5b(?:$fws?$dcontent)*$fws?\\x5d$cfws?)";


    ####################################################################################
    #
    # local-part      =       dot-atom / quoted-string / obs-local-part
    # domain          =       dot-atom / domain-literal / obs-domain
    # addr-spec       =       local-part "@" domain

    $local_part = "(($dot_atom)|($quoted_string)|($obs_local_part))";
    $domain     = "(($dot_atom)|($domain_literal)|($obs_domain))";
    $addr_spec  = "$local_part\\x40$domain";



    #
    # this was previously 256 based on RFC3696, but dominic's errata was accepted.
    #

    if (strlen($email) > 254) return 0;


    #
    # we need to strip nested comments first - we replace them with a simple comment
    #

    if ($options['allow_comments']){

        $email = email_strip_comments($outer_comment, $email, "(x)");
    }


    #
    # now match what's left
    #

    if (!preg_match("!^$addr_spec$!", $email, $m)){

        return 0;
    }

    $bits = array(
        'local'         => isset($m[1]) ? $m[1] : '',
        'local-atom'        => isset($m[2]) ? $m[2] : '',
        'local-quoted'      => isset($m[3]) ? $m[3] : '',
        'local-obs'     => isset($m[4]) ? $m[4] : '',
        'domain'        => isset($m[5]) ? $m[5] : '',
        'domain-atom'       => isset($m[6]) ? $m[6] : '',
        'domain-literal'    => isset($m[7]) ? $m[7] : '',
        'domain-obs'        => isset($m[8]) ? $m[8] : '',
    );


    #
    # we need to now strip comments from $bits[local] and $bits[domain],
    # since we know they're in the right place and we want them out of the
    # way for checking IPs, label sizes, etc
    #

    if ($options['allow_comments']){
        $bits['local']  = email_strip_comments($comment, $bits['local']);
        $bits['domain'] = email_strip_comments($comment, $bits['domain']);
    }


    #
    # length limits on segments
    #

    if (strlen($bits['local']) > 64) return 0;
    if (strlen($bits['domain']) > 255) return 0;


    #
    # restrictions on domain-literals from RFC2821 section 4.1.3
    #
    # RFC4291 changed the meaning of :: in IPv6 addresses - i can mean one or
    # more zero groups (updated from 2 or more).
    #

    if (strlen($bits['domain-literal'])){

        $Snum           = "(\d{1,3})";
        $IPv4_address_literal   = "$Snum\.$Snum\.$Snum\.$Snum";

        $IPv6_hex       = "(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})";

        $IPv6_full      = "IPv6\:$IPv6_hex(?:\:$IPv6_hex){7}";

        $IPv6_comp_part     = "(?:$IPv6_hex(?:\:$IPv6_hex){0,7})?";
        $IPv6_comp      = "IPv6\:($IPv6_comp_part\:\:$IPv6_comp_part)";

        $IPv6v4_full        = "IPv6\:$IPv6_hex(?:\:$IPv6_hex){5}\:$IPv4_address_literal";

        $IPv6v4_comp_part   = "$IPv6_hex(?:\:$IPv6_hex){0,5}";
        $IPv6v4_comp        = "IPv6\:((?:$IPv6v4_comp_part)?\:\:(?:$IPv6v4_comp_part\:)?)$IPv4_address_literal";


        #
        # IPv4 is simple
        #

        if (preg_match("!^\[$IPv4_address_literal\]$!", $bits['domain'], $m)){

            if (intval($m[1]) > 255) return 0;
            if (intval($m[2]) > 255) return 0;
            if (intval($m[3]) > 255) return 0;
            if (intval($m[4]) > 255) return 0;

        }else{

            #
            # this should be IPv6 - a bunch of tests are needed here :)
            #

            while (1){

                if (preg_match("!^\[$IPv6_full\]$!", $bits['domain'])){
                    break;
                }

                if (preg_match("!^\[$IPv6_comp\]$!", $bits['domain'], $m)){
                    list($a, $b) = explode('::', $m[1]);
                    $folded = (strlen($a) && strlen($b)) ? "$a:$b" : "$a$b";
                    $groups = explode(':', $folded);
                    if (count($groups) > 7) return 0;
                    break;
                }

                if (preg_match("!^\[$IPv6v4_full\]$!", $bits['domain'], $m)){

                    if (intval($m[1]) > 255) return 0;
                    if (intval($m[2]) > 255) return 0;
                    if (intval($m[3]) > 255) return 0;
                    if (intval($m[4]) > 255) return 0;
                    break;
                }

                if (preg_match("!^\[$IPv6v4_comp\]$!", $bits['domain'], $m)){
                    list($a, $b) = explode('::', $m[1]);
                    $b = substr($b, 0, -1); # remove the trailing colon before the IPv4 address
                    $folded = (strlen($a) && strlen($b)) ? "$a:$b" : "$a$b";
                    $groups = explode(':', $folded);
                    if (count($groups) > 5) return 0;
                    break;
                }

                return 0;
            }
        }           
    }else{

        #
        # the domain is either dot-atom or obs-domain - either way, it's
        # made up of simple labels and we split on dots
        #

        $labels = explode('.', $bits['domain']);


        #
        # this is allowed by both dot-atom and obs-domain, but is un-routeable on the
        # public internet, so we'll fail it (e.g. user@localhost)
        #

        if ($options['public_internet']){
            if (count($labels) == 1) return 0;
        }


        #
        # checks on each label
        #

        foreach ($labels as $label){

            if (strlen($label) > 63) return 0;
            if (substr($label, 0, 1) == '-') return 0;
            if (substr($label, -1) == '-') return 0;
        }


        #
        # last label can't be all numeric
        #

        if ($options['public_internet']){
            if (preg_match('!^[0-9]+$!', array_pop($labels))) return 0;
        }
    }


    return 1;
}

##################################################################################

function email_strip_comments($comment, $email, $replace=''){

    while (1){
        $new = preg_replace("!$comment!", $replace, $email);
        if (strlen($new) == strlen($email)){
            return $email;
        }
        $email = $new;
    }
}

##################################################################################
?>
```

Ela é utilizada pelo FW Solar PHP

Answer (score -1):

Esta função retorna verdadeiro se o `$email` informado se encaixa no padrão estabelecido no regex: `fulano@dominio.com`

```php
function valida_email($email) {
return preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/', $email)
}
```

Comment: Explique um pouco melhor como este código se encaixa na solução do problema que o @Zuul tem.

Comment: Esta função retorna verdadeiro se o $email informado se encaixa no padrão estabelecido no regex: fulano@dominio.com.

Answer (score -1):

Eu apostaria em experssões regulares. Pela RFC5322 ser mais nova que a RFC822 então tentaria uma expressão que a validasse, como esta aqui:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*
@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

Mas esta expressão acima ainda permite asdf@asdf.asdf, o que é um pouco incomodo. Então poderia se optar por adicionar os domínios, talvez fizesse parte de uma whitelist, exemplo:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|
biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b
```

Mas também é incomodo ficar colocando domínios mundiais, o tempo todo são adicionado novos domínios.

Acho que estas expressões são os melhores caminhos, do meu ponto de vista.

Este é o site que costumo pesquisar estas espressões [aqui](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Answer (score -2):

Dá pra montar uma função usando expressões regulares...

```
function validaEmail($email) {
    $conta = "^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@";
    $domino = "[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+.";
    $extensao = "([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";

    $pattern = $conta.$domino.$extensao;
    if (preg_match($pattern, $email))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

// Define uma variável para testar o validador
$input = "meuemail@dominio.com.br";
// Faz a verificação usando a função
if (validaEmail($input)) {
    echo "O e-mail inserido é valido!";
} else {
    echo "O e-mail inserido é invalido!";
}
```

Retirado do blog do Thiago Belém...

http://blog.thiagobelem.net/validacao-de-e-mail-no-php-com-expressoes-regulares/